# Ignore nonexistent table columns in function

Tags: r

I have a simple function:

```
code_ppd_table <- function(n){
  table_1 <- cbind(t13[,n], t14[,n], t15[,n], t16[,n], t17[,n])
  colnames(table_1) <- c('cy13', 'cy14', 'cy15', 'cy16', 'cy17')
  table_1
}
```

In this function t13, t14, etc are tables.  When I run the function, I obtain the desired table from each of t13, t14, etc which have column names "n" (i.e. the table has columns t13[,'n'], t14[,'n'], etc).  However, if one of the tables happens to not have a column with name "n" (so, for example, if t15[,'n'] does not exist), I get an error.  How can I tell R to ignore any table which does not have column "n", and only give me the other ones?

Comment: In the text of the question you mention `t13[,'n']`, etc, but in the code it's `t13[,n]` without quotes. Which is it, the string `'n'` or the vector `n`?

Comment: The string, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
# some data with n == hp  
t13 <- mtcars[1:4,]
t14 <- mtcars[11:14,]
t15 <- mtcars[11:14,-4]


# function and vector to change colnames
t_names <- c("t13", "t14", "t15")
change_colname <- function(df, new_colname){
  df %>% rename_all(funs(paste0(.,"_",new_colname)))
}

# code
list(t13, t14, t15) %>% 
  map2(.,t_names, ~change_colname(.x,.y)) %>% 
  bind_cols() %>% 
  select(starts_with("hp"))
  hp_t13 hp_t14
1    110    123
2    110    180
3     93    180
4    110    180
```

Dependent on what you want to do with the data afterwards, you can also try to bind the data rowwise:

```
list(t13=t13, t14=t14, t15=t15) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "source") %>% 
  select(source, hp) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(hp))
  source  hp
1    t13 110
2    t13 110
3    t13  93
4    t13 110
5    t14 123
6    t14 180
7    t14 180
8    t14 180
```

Instead of the filter step you can add:

```
list(t13=t13, t14=t14, t15=t15) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "source") %>% 
  select(source, hp) %>%
  group_by(source) %>% 
  mutate(n=row_number()) %>% 
  spread(source, hp)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
      n   t13   t14   t15
* <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   110   123    NA
2     2   110   180    NA
3     3    93   180    NA
4     4   110   180    NA
```